# Redirect Domain Name to Localhost

Tags: linux, localhost, redirection

I have a linux test machine which I would like to run a copy of a production webserver. This is a legacy application which does not use a property file for its server name. Throughout the application, the server name is hardcoded (example: open connection to myServer.myCompany.com).

Is there any linux trick which I can use to redirect all requests for a certain host back to localhost? I know in Windows that I can add an entry to the hosts file and have it redirect back to localhost. How do I do this in linux?

Answer (score 32):

Add the following line to /etc/hosts:

> `127.0.0.1 myserver.mycompany.com`

Comment: Will that work if myserver.mycompany.com is sometimes referenced by http and other times with https? Even with different ports (besides 80)?

Comment: Yes, it will.  You're only specifying what IP myserver.mycompany.com resolves to.  It doesn't matter what service you're connecting to on that IP.  /etc/hosts is at OSI layer 3, the services are a layer 4 construct.

Comment: I did exactly that on Debian 8 Jessie. And it aint work: `host workflows.devbg.us` returns `Host workflows.devbg.us not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`.

Comment: It's well known that nslookup/host don't look at /etc/hosts.  Try pinging the host, it should give you the proper IP.  Or try using a browser to hit it.