# Proxying fake domain to a localhost port

Tags: mac, proxy, redirection, web-development, localhost

I'd like to do much the same thing described at [Redirect Domain Name to Localhost](https://superuser.com/questions/147653/redirect-domain-name-to-localhost) for web app development purposes, but with the twist that I'd like requests to `fakedomain.com:80` to be routed to `localhost:8080`, say, so that I don't have to actually use my development machine's port 80.

I'd welcome answers that take the form of:

- Small changes to configuration files like `/etc/hosts`, and/or
- An easy-to-configure proxy server I could run

**Note**: [Pow](http://pow.cx/) takes the approach of setting a firewall rule to forward *all* incoming traffic on port 80 to port 20559. That may be an acceptable solution, but ideally, I'd like to forward only a specific domain + port combination.

Comment: Do you already have a webserver running on port 80?  If so does it support url rewriting?

Comment: @Paul I may have different things running on port 80 at different times. So I'd prefer a solution that can run in front of the webserver.

Answer (score 2):

The whole 127.0.0.0/8 range belongs to your local machine. You don't have to use 127.0.0.1 alone.

You can point your (fake) domain to 127.0.0.2 in your hosts and setup your server to bind just to that IP as opposed to all IPs. In Windows and Linux, the most specific binding wins if there's a conflict, so your binding for 127.0.0.2:80 overrides the one for *:80.

Comment: Interesting. I'd appreciate Mac-specific instructions for doing this.

Comment: It's almost exactly the same story. You modify `/etc/hosts` and change the apache/whatever configuration file to make the relevant virtual host `Listen` to the 127.x.y.z IP.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use an external device. I'd set up port forwarding on your firewall / router, on port 80, to point to your computer's port 8080, where `fakedomain` has an entry in your hosts file pointing to your external firewall / router.