# Redirecting/aliasing domain to localhost for development

Tags: networking, redirection, localhost, hosts-file

**How do I configure /etc/hosts so that if I go to `google.com` it's actually routed to my `localhost:3000`**?

I'm aware of [similar questions](https://superuser.com/questions/147653/redirect-domain-name-to-localhost).

Here is what my hosts file looks like right now:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
#127.0.0.1      localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       myapp.herokuapp.com
```

You wouldn't believe how many similar questions I've looked up and how many combinations of localhost, 127.0.0.1 and myapp I've tried.

Answer (score -1):

Use your IP address
On my computer I would put this in my etc file:
192.168.0.159  google.com

But beware, this will inhibit access to google!

Comment: That won't redirect to `localhost:3000` (note the port number), which is what OP asked for.